# Unable to create signed .apk for React-native App

Tags: android, react-native

I am unable to create signed .apk for my react-native app.
Below is the command after creating keystore file

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

and below is the output on terminal

```
Support for running Gradle using Java 6 has been deprecated and will be removed in Gradle 3.0
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/rishabh.bhardwaj/Desktop/MyReactProjects/museumreact/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Try menu File - > Invalidate caches and restart. Make sure that you are using the latest gradle plugins. Try to update your JDK in "Project Structure" options.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?